# How do I make a formula that updates when I enter a new value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

This question is hard to explain, but here I go. So I have this column of numbers, and I have another cell that I want to put a formula in. I want the formula to subtract the latest value in the column from the newest value in the column, if that makes sense.

Basically Im starting to cut weight, and wanted an easy way to keep track of it. So the first number is my starting weight, and each day Im going to enter my weight in the column below, so that I after a month I will have a column of my last 30 weights. I want the formula to automatically change the second value in the subtraction problem each time I enter a new weight.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a little bit on your data setup. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in cell D3 will subtract the last number it can find in column B from the number in B2.

```
=B2-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(99^99,B:B,1))
```

Does that help?

Comment: Interesting approach! According to manual, range has to be sorted in an ascending order, are you sure this formula always works?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yes. Try it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: It works because it isn't really matching anything.  It looks for a huge number and when it can't find it, defaults to the last value, which is the objective in this case.